# AWS Load Balancer + NginX + EC2 AutoScaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Currently, I dont have AWS Load Balancer setup yet.

Request comes to a single ec2 instance: first hits nginx which then gets forwarded to node/express.

Now, I want to create an autoscaling group, and attach AWS load balancer to distribute the request that comes in. I am wondering if this is a good setup:

```
Request -> AWS Load Balancer -> Nginx A + EC2 A
                             -> Nginx B + EC2 B
                             -> ... C   + ... C
```

Nginx is installed on the same EC2 that has node.js running on it. Nginx config has logic to detect user's location using the geoip module, as well as gzip compression configs and ssl handling.

I will also move the ssl handling to the load balancer.

Comment: What is the formal criteria to evaluate whether it's "good" or not?

Comment: Are your Nginx servers on different EC2 instances from your backend EC2 instances? If yes, your design will not work with AWS Autoscaling. Unless Nginx is part of your design, I would drop them and Autoscale your backend EC2 instances behind an ALB. If your Nginx instances are on the same EC2 instance as your EC2 A, .. then adding Autoscaling and ALB is OK.

Comment: No, the nginx is installed on the EC2 instance that is also running node.js. The nginx has logic to determine user's location as well as gzip compression stuff. And by good design, I mean that it should scale and perform robustly. Ideally i want to know the best practice used in biggest tech sites.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally *(if Nginx can be decoupled from specific Node tasks)* you'd want an auto scaling group dedicated to each service and I'd suggest using [containerization](https://cloud.google.com/containers/) for this because this is exactly what its meant for, though all this will obviously require some non-trivial changes to your program...

[image]

This will enable...

**Efficient Resource Allocation**

- Select instance types with the ideal mix of CPU/RAM/Network/Storage per service (Node or Nginx)
- Maintain granular control over the amount of tasks running relative their actual demand.

**Intelligent Scaling**

Thresholds set to initialize scaling actions need to reflect the resources they're running. You may not want to say, double your more compute intensive Node capacity, when there are spikes in simple read operations to your program. By segmenting the services by resources the thresholds can be tied to the resource your service demands the most of. You may want to scale...

- Nginx based on maximum inbound requests over 1 minute period
- Node based on average CPU Utilization over 5 minute period

The 'chunks' that your instances are broken into relative to the size of you tasks also makes a big difference in how efficient they will scale. Here's an exaggerated example, on just one service...

1. 1 EC2 t3.large running 5 Node tasks @ 50% RAM Utilization.
2. AS group Hits 70% or whatever thresholds you assigned, scales-out 1 instance
3. 2 instances now running say 6 Node tasks @ 30% RAM Utilization

This causes 2 problems...

- You're now wasting a lot of money
- Possibly more importantly... what is you scale-in threshold? 20% Utilization?

The tighter the gaps of you upper and lower scaling bounds the more efficient you'll be. When the tasks you're running are all homogenous you can add and remove in smaller and more precise 'chunks' of resources.

In the scenario above you'd ideally want something like...

1. 3 t3.small instances running 5 Node tasks
2. AS group hits 70% Utilization, scales-out 1 instance
3. Now you have 6 tasks on 4 instances at 50% utilization
4. Utilization drops to 40% scale-in 1 instance.

You can obviously still do all of this running Node and Nginx on the same underlying resources, but the mathematics of it all gets pretty crazy and makes your system brittle.

*(I've simplified the above to target Memory **Utilization** on the AS group, but in application you'd have ECS adding tasks based on Utillzation, which then adds to the memory **Reservation** of the cluster, which would then initiate the AS actions.)*

**Simplified & Efficient Deployment**

- You don't want to be redeploying your whole Node code base for every update to Nginx configuration.
- Simplifies Blue/Green deployments testing and rollbacks.
- Minimize the resources you have to spin up for the 'Blue' portion of you deployments.
- Use customized AMIs with pre installed binaries if needed fro only the serivce dependent on them

Whether you want to do it immediately or not (and you will) this configuration will allow you to move to [Spot Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/) to handle more of your variable workloads. Like all of this, you can still use Spot Instances with the configuration you've laid out, but handling termination procedures efficiently and without disruptions is a whole other mess and when you get to that you want the rest of this very organized and working smoothly.

[ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/)

[NLB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html)

I don't know what you're using for deployment, but [AWS CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/) will work beautifully with [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) to manage you container clusters as well.